# Highcharts tootip for stacked bar charts

Tags: highcharts

I have a  3 stacked bar charts for each element is there any options to show a tooltip to show individual shared tooptip for each stack bar.

For Eg : If there are 3 stacked bar charts for each element showing 
Bar 1 (A,B,C,D)(stacked)
Bar 2 (E,F,G,H)(stacked)
Bar 3 (I)(normal bar)

I want to show a tooptip for each bar eg showing (A,B,C,D) on mouse over of Bar1
and showing (E,F,G,H) on mouse over Bar 2 and showing (I) on mouse over Bar 3 with their series name.

Can some one help me on this ?

Comment: What you mean individual shared tooltip ? You can have shared, display all values or disabled sharing and display only one "value".

Comment: Since it is stacked bar, i have 3 stacked bars for each element.So i want to show a tooltip stacking all the values as one tooltip for bar 1 bar 2 and bar 3

Comment: @SebastianBochan So I guess the question is how to show tooltips for individual stacks, each stack have several bars, and we can have multiple stacks. We need to show info on each stack. Do you know how to do that

Answer (score 4):

You can use shared parameted for tooltip

http://jsfiddle.net/nAkWg/

```
tooltip: {
            shared:true
        },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared

Comment: I have 3 bars for each person .. how to show individual tooptip for each bar.. In that 2 are stacked and one is normal

Comment: I know there is an option for toolip to be shared my question is how to keep shared tooptip for 2 stacked bar charts and not shared for the other one